# Additional question

Tags: discussion

How should be asked additional question, that is not essential to be answered by user who responds to the question?

Should the question consist multiple questions that explains better the issue or not?

How to prioritise questions so the user won't hesitate to respond if he/she does not know the answer to additional question?